# Can't set Context in async function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-context

Okay so be gentle on me, I am pretty new to React Native but I am using Context to manage some of the state in my React Native project. Here is an example of where I am stuck

At the top of the functional component I have this...

```
import DataContext from "../../contexts/DataContext";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const AccountHomepageScreen = ({navigation}) => {

     const { data, updateInfo} = useContext(DataContext);


     const getUserFromAsync = async () => {
         try {
             const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
             if(value !== null) {

                 //shows user_id in Alert no problem
                 alert(value);

                 //but this does not work?!?!
                 updateInfo('userId', value);
            
             }
         } catch(e) {
             // error reading value
            return false;
         }
     }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getUserFromAsync();
}, []);
```

in The context file updateInfo does the following

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const DataContext = React.createContext();


export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [info, setInfo] = useState({
    userId: '',
    textText: 'Connected!!!',
    availableBusinesses : [],
    getBusinessesError: ''
});

const updateInfo = (field, val) => {
    setInfo({
        ...info, [field]: val
    });
};

return (
         <DataContext.Provider value={{
             data: {info},
             updateInfo
         }}>
         {children}
         </DataContext.Provider>
     );

};

export default DataContext;
```

Comment: `//but this does not work?!?!` can you be more specific? What are you expecting to happen? You may need to show us what updateInfo's code is.

Comment: I actually am calling it inside useEffect, I just forgot to include that. Sorry, yes, I am trying to set the Context with the userID value

Comment: I have added the DataContext File as well

Comment: Thanks. And what's the problem that's happening? Did you stick a log statement in the body of your component (not in the use effect or getUserFromAsync) and it's not rerendering?

Comment: The Context will not update with the value. The value is there though because it shows up in the alert. I just do not understand why the Context does not get updated with the script. It works everywhere else. I can only assume it has something to do with the async function its being called in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const updateInfo = (field, val) => {
    setInfo(info => ({
        ...info, [field]: val
    }));
};
```

This is a piece of magic code. Try if it solve your problem ;-)

---

#### Expanation

I saw this kind of mistakes so many times among React newbies. It's the classic *stale closure* problem.

So `updateInfo`'s closure captures `info` (which is later used as in `...info`), then `getUserFromAsync`'s closure captures `updateInfo`, and finally the callback of `useEffect` captures `getUserFromAsync`.

Now because `useEffect`'s deplist is empty, its callback closure is never gonna update, it stuck at the first snapshot ever created. Thus that closure will become a stale closure, aka "get out of sync", from the very first state change after its creation.

And because of the closure chain mentioned above, the whole chain is stall, starting from the calling point `useEffect` callback. Thus the updated `info` value is NOT gonna reflect via `setState({ ...info })` call...

UNLESS you avoid the capturing/snapshoting behavior from the beginning! The magic code just does that. It avoid referencing `info` through closure capturing, instead it takes that value from callback function param provided by

```
setState(info => ...)
```

Although the closure chain is still `stale`, but it dealt no real damage cus it references no outside value. `setState` will ensure the `info` param is always set to latest state value.

Comment: That explains why it worked on updating some values outside of useEffect. Thanks again for the help and the detailed explanation of why it would never work. These all day struggles with problems will definitely make me better at it. I learn best like that for sure and with the help of professionals like you. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you're probably trying to update something on your component through the `updateInfo` function.

In that case, it all depends on where are you calling the `getUserFromAsync` function.

If you want to call it as soon as the `AccountHomepageScreen` is loaded, then you can use a `hook` (check the hooks documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)).

Using `useEffect` will make sure that your code is being executed only when the component is rendered on the screen, so the function will actually affect the layout:

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'; // Import it where you're already importing useContext
import DataContext from "../../contexts/DataContext";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-community/async-storage";

const AccountHomepageScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { data, updateInfo } = useContext(DataContext);

  // Calling the hook
  useEffect(() => {
    getUserFromAsync();
  });

  const getUserFromAsync = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user_id");
      if (value !== null) {
        //shows user_id in Alert no problem
        alert(value);

        // you should be able to call the updateInfo function now
        updateInfo("userId", value);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
      return false;
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Thanks rleiva93, I appreciate the effort, but that is what I had used already and should have posted it all. Sorry for that. I did not want to use redux as a state management tool but may have to look into that. I just cannot understand why the Context does not get updated inside of getUserFromAsync When the alert right before that has the correct value. Thanks again for the attempt though